# What's a good workbench tool for sqlite similar to MySQLWorkbench for MySQL?

Tags: sqlite, tools

What's a good workbench tool for sqlite similar to MySQLWorkbench for MySQL?   I'm used to MySQLWorkbench for working with MySQL databases.  Now I have some sqlite databases to work with and would like to find a similar tool.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403/is-there-a-good-ide-for-sqlite, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601410/mysql-workbench-with-sqlite, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332250/windows-gui-tool-for-sqlite3, and [Software Recommendations.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I particularly like [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager-webext/) which works from within your (firefox) browser. If you're not a firefox user, then [here](http://alternativeto.net/software/sqlite-manager/) is a list of alternatives.

Comment: Did you miss the hyperlink for 'this one'?

Comment: Oooops.... :-) .

Comment: Broken link for "this one" again

Comment: @qazwsx - link restored - HTH!

Comment: @ZackKnopp - link restored - thanks for pointing it out! HTH!